# TesseractOCRiOS | Warning: Multiple build commands for output file

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, tesseract

**versions:**
TesseractOCRiOS 4.0.0
CocoaPods 1.2.1

When i'm building on simulator - everything is fine, but when i'm trying to build on my iPhone xCode gives me next warning:

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-hjheurpncvhpfbabezufoumrybad/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR.framework/PrivateHeaders/config_auto.h
```

Answer (score 3):

Faced with the same problem recently, definitely not the best, but acceptable workaround - just delete one of the duplicate lines "config_auto.h" with path "./Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/include/leptonica/" in "Build Phases"-"Headers"-"Private" settings of TesseractOCRiOS target.

OCR recognition functionality does not affected by this change.

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7SQo.png) for details.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using cocoapods, you can add following script at the end of your pod file:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name == 'TesseractOCRiOS' 
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
            end
            header_phase = target.build_phases().select do |phase|
                phase.is_a? Xcodeproj::Project::PBXHeadersBuildPhase
            end.first

            duplicated_header_files = header_phase.files.select do |file|
                file.display_name == 'config_auto.h'
            end

            duplicated_header_files.each do |file|
                header_phase.remove_build_file file
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Just noticed that it's also disabling bitcode. Remove it if that's not what you need. The script removes the duplicate header files since they are under private section only.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem in your project directory. You have a duplicate file of config_auto.h
Go to your Target , Delete config_auto.h under the build phases.

Hope!! This helps you